# Perl signatures: Can Lists be substituted by Scalars?

Tags: perl, list, scalar

Take a look at one of the print subroutines of perl:

```
print FILEHANDLE LIST
```

(http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html)

I tried it out and it seems that you can also pass a scalar instead of a list. Is that a general rule in perl that wherever a list is demanded you can pass in a scalar? Is the scalar automatically converted to a list then?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A list with one element is still a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only pass a list of scalars to some function in perl.

> Is that a general rule in perl that wherever a list is demanded you can pass in a scalar?

Yes, in such case you have one element long list.

`print()` takes `($one, $two, $three)` as list in same way as `@arr`, or `map $_, @arr`, or `$arr[0], $arr[1], $arr[2]`

Comment: With "You can only pass a list of scalars to some function in perl.", are you referring to built in subroutines only am I right? I mean it is possible to define a function which takes a scalar in the end or not?

Comment: @user2820379 can you explain how such function look like?

Comment: Never mind. I just did a little research about routines in perl. Seems I had a wrong concept in my mind. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Re "are you referring to built in subroutines only am I right?", No. Prototypes may make it look like you can pass something else, but even them, only scalars are passed to the subroutine.

Answer (score 2):

`LIST` refers to a an expression that returns a list of zero or more scalars. It's basically the same thing as `EXPR`, except with the implication that it's called in list context.

```
print($fh ());         # "()" is a placeholder that avoids the default to $_
print($fh $foo);
print($fh $foo, $bar);
print($fh @array);
print($fh map uc, @a);
```

etc

There is no list data structure. It's just a concept and metaphor.

Answer (score 1):

Within a subroutine, Perl assumes that you called the subroutine with a list of arguments.

That's why, if your subroutine is called

```
my_subroutine ($a, $b, $c);
```

within the subroutine, you can do

```
sub my_subroutine
{
    my $x = shift;
    my $y = shift;
    my $z = shift;
...
    #Or, my ($x, $y, $z) = @_;
```

By calling shift, you're implicitly calling shift on @_, which is an array of the passed in arguments.